# Pine script v5 input.timeframe range selection

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to get a range selection in TradingView's pine script? Currently the following code provides only a list with "Minutes", "Hours", and "Days" time frames but no selection for "Ranges":

```
input.timeframe(defval="", "Select a time frame")
```

Regards,

**EDIT:** the documentation states that range charts use 1 minute data. It looks as if it is not possible to directly use range chart bars in pine script.

Answer (score 0):

input.timeframe(title="Week time frame", defval="W")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).